# How To Subscribe multiple Publications in meteor without waiting for each other and not using unblock package?

Tags: meteor

How To **Subscribe multiple Publications** in meteor without waiting for each other and not using unblock package??

Answer (score 2):

You can register one publish function and return array of cursors:

```
Meteor.publish('yourPublications', function () {
  return [yourPublication1Data, yourPublication2Data, yourPublicationData3];
});
```

And subscribe only once:

```
Meteor.subscribe('yourPublications');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this.unblock(); in your publication to unblock:

```
Meteor.publish('yourPublications1', function() {
  this.unblock();
  return yourPublication1Data;
}

Meteor.publish('yourPublications2', function() {
  this.unblock();
  return yourPublication2Data;
}

Meteor.publish('yourPublications3', function() {
  this.unblock();
  return yourPublicationData3;
}
```

Then you can subscribe these publication on route or template render.

```
Meteor.subscribe('yourPublications1');
Meteor.subscribe('yourPublications2');
Meteor.subscribe('yourPublications3');
```

Comment: this.unblock is not available for publications, at least not out of the box. You can use a package for that.

Comment: Here is the doc for same; https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-unblock

Comment: it is an API for methods, not publications. But I conincidentally needed to unblock pubs, so I installed lamhieu:unblock and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will need the package or code the same thing like the package does, yourself. I just installed lamhieu:unblock and it works great. But I don't fully understand what it is doing - that code is a bit high level for me.